# Is there any easy way to get the "reader view" content of a website with any Node.js libraries?

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping

I have tried multiple scrapers, but I didn't find a way to easily extract the main view of a website (only main text and images), just like iOS does it with the Reader View in Safari.